# Who coined (or popularized) the term "SLAM"?

Tags: slam

According to [Wikipedia's article on SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping), the original idea came from Randal Smith and Peter Cheeseman (*[On the Estimation and Representation of Spatial Uncertainty](http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/%7Ehpm/project.archive/reference.file/Smith&Cheeseman.pdf)* [PDF]) in 1986, and was refined by Hugh F. Durrant-Whyte and J.J. Leonard (*[Simultaneous map building and localization for an autonomous mobile robot](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/174711)*) in 1991.

However, neither paper uses the term "SLAM".  Where (and when) did that term come from?  Was there a particular author or whitepaper that popularized it?

Comment: I ask because I'm working on a paper that has a similar "simultaneously do X and use X to do Y" subject, and I'm curious about what made the idea -- complicated as it is to implement -- compelling enough to become ubiquitous.  I'd like to see how it was presented, and what was the state of the art at the time.

Comment: +1 for "Simultaneous map building and localization for an autonomous mobile robot".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [SLAM tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.berkeley.edu%2F~pabbeel%2Fcs287-fa09%2Freadings%2FDurrant-Whyte_Bailey_SLAM-tutorial-I.pdf&ei=qB26UJ7BJcGUrgeUoYHgCg&usg=AFQjCNHglzCdyHwwV9DdjXlTprqMQTcrwA),

> The structure of the SLAM problem, the convergence result and the
>   coining of the acronym ‘SLAM’ was ﬁrst presented in a mobile robotics survey 
>   paper presented at the 1995 International Sym- posium on
>   Robotics Research.

which refers to this paper ->

> H. Durrant-Whyte, D. Rye, and E. Nebot. Localisation of automatic
>   guided vehicles. In G. Giralt and G. Hirzinger, editors, Robotics
>   Research: The 7th International Symposium (ISRR’95), pages 613–625.
>   Springer Verlag, 1996.

Comment: It's a sad day when a researcher can't even cite his own paper correctly ... According to Springer, at least, the paper is called "[Localization of Autonomous Guided Vehicles](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4471-1021-7_69)", which makes it at least findable in Google Scholar as a citation, though I can't get at the original either.

Comment: @ThomasH No wonder it wasnt turning up anything on Google

Comment: John Leonard confirms this in [his talk](https://youtu.be/x5CZmlaMNCs?t=2510)